# jquerymobile listview anchor tag not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a listview (jquerymobile) with 5 `<ul> <li>` items as follows -

```
    <div class="ticketsBlock" data-theme="a">      
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none" data-transition="slide"><p>John Smith</p><p>2 Cadeau Terr London ON N6K 4G1</p><br/><p>Issue with set-top box</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none"><p>Sylvester Stallone</p><p>64 Faywood Dr Brampton ON L6Y 4L95</p><br/><p>New Connection</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none"><p>Antenna Replacement</p><p>14 Grand St Brantford ON N3R 4B1</p><br/><p>New Connection</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none"><p>Keanu Reaves</p><p>5617 Fourth Line Hillsburgh ON N0B 1Z0</p><br/><p>Distorted Display</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none"><p>Tom Cruise</p><p>RR5 Perth ON K7H 3C7</p><br/><p>Issue with set-top box</p></a></li>
</ul>                
        </div>
```

The href in each `<li>` is referring to a div tag within same HTML page, whose data role is "page" -

```
<div data-role="page" id="custDetails" data-theme="a">
   <button class="ui-btn-left" id="backbutton" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">Back</button>
    <h1>XXX</h1>
    <button class="ui-btn-right" id="exit" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right">Exit</button>
  <div data-role="content"> Content </div>
 <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" class="ui-footer-fixed">
    <h4>myFooter</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

This html page has different div-s with their data-role as "page" as per JQM's standards. Now when I click on the list item which is referring to a div (data-role as page), it is not navigating to that div.

But yes, it's working if I give link to a different HTML page instead of a div inside same HTML page.

Anyone, kindly let me know where there is a problem with this approach? Would this approach work at all?

Comment: Can you add your full HTML page. Without it we can only guess.

Comment: Your listview is within a different data-role=page? Are you sure that all tags are closed properly? if one `</div>` is missing, it will ruin the whole setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/ttjGv/2/

It goes to that div. Check the html markup below.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="my-header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">            
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ticketsBlock" data-theme="a">      
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none" data-transition="slide"><p>John Smith</p><p>2 Cadeau Terr London ON N6K 4G1</p><br/><p>Issue with set-top box</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none"><p>Sylvester Stallone</p><p>64 Faywood Dr Brampton ON L6Y 4L95</p><br/><p>New Connection</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none"><p>Antenna Replacement</p><p>14 Grand St Brantford ON N3R 4B1</p><br/><p>New Connection</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none"><p>Keanu Reaves</p><p>5617 Fourth Line Hillsburgh ON N0B 1Z0</p><br/><p>Distorted Display</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#custDetails" style="text-decoration:none"><p>Tom Cruise</p><p>RR5 Perth ON K7H 3C7</p><br/><p>Issue with set-top box</p></a></li>
</ul>                
        </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- page -->
```

Comment: hi @yeyene... I am absolutely not sure what's wrong my machine then? The same thing doesn't work on my machine. Is it something related to the JQM version I am using?

Comment: @yeyene.. I found it.. it's the problem with a </div> -I missed out one :(